# Testing Instagram Graph API stopped returning media

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0, instagram-graph-api

I'm developing website so my fb app is in dev mode and until yesterday everything worked fine. Today I can not figure out what went wrong.

I used page token to get my Instagram business account connected to my page: `me?fields=connected_instagram_account`. Now it tells me: "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token."

Then I used to use:

```
{Instagram ID}?fields=media.limit(10){comments_count,like_count,media_url,permalink,caption}
```

But I don't have Instagram ID anymore.

- So I checked that my Instagram is really connected to my Fb page and it really is.
- Then I tried to regenerate access token. Everything looks good.
  [image]
- In my app are also needed "App Review for Instagram" such as "instagram_basic, instagram_manage_insights but my app is in development mode so it should not be needed. Over more I can not add Submission sice I have nothing like Privacy Policy URL.

Where can be a problem?? I just need to fetch media from my Instagram account.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are experiencing the same issue like me. Did you already try the same steps for resolving the issue that I am describing in my question?

[Using Instagram Graph Api with permanent page access token only works for some accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033362/using-instagram-graph-api-with-permanent-page-access-token-only-works-for-some-a)

Comment: I just read your post and it seems you have encountered exactly the same issue.  My opinion is that it is Facebook's mess and I don't know what is right behaviour. Maybe even they don't know but it is definitely weird that one day page access token works and another day it doesn't. In your case that for one account page access token works and for another it doesn't. About the steps you wrote... I only tried regenerate new access token but it didn't help. My workaround is just using user access token. However if you find out something please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since yesterday I can use the permanent page access token again and everything works like before. Seems like facebook resolved an internal bug.

Answer (score 0):

So since yesterday it is not possible to use in this case page token but user token. I believe it is Facebook's bug.