# Using Instagram Graph Api with permanent page access token only works for some accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-access-token, instagram-graph-api

I try to fetch some images from an instagram business account through the instagram graph api by means of a permanent **page access token** ([facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token/28418469#28418469)). These specific tokens seem to be the only possibility to get permanent access to the graph api for a **server-side app**.

On the other side I found a hint in the fb documentation that only user accesss tokens can be used to access instagram business accounts.

> "Page access tokens are not supported."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/?locale=en_US

Funny enough I was using page tokens so far without any problems. After resetting the database of my project and generating new tokens I observered that some accounts weren't able to fetch the data while others had no problems.

> "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."

I had 2 instagram accounts: 1 was working with page access tokens the other didn't. So, I checked it in the fb graph explorer. Using the user access token I have no problem with both accounts. Using the page access token respectivly for both accounts one is working fine for the query while the other isn't. A third account that I created has the same problem.

**Things I tried to resolve the issue:**

1. deleting all permanent page access tokens from my database and generate them again
2. generate the permanent page access tokens manually by means of the fb graph explorer tool
3. turn my instagram account back into personal and then again into a business account through the app
4. turn my instagram account back into personal and then again into a business account through the facebook page
5. create a new instagram account and a new facebook page to connect (repeating 3. and 4.)

**My questions now:**

1. Can I use permanent page access tokens for the instagram graph api?
2. If not, how do I get permanent server side access to the instagram graph api?

I am now searching the internet and stackoverflow for days and getting crazy because I seem to be the only person experiencing this problem. So, help will be highly appreciated by my fellow developers. Tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since yesterday everything works fine again also when using the permanent page access token. Seems like fb resolved an internal bug. However, the question remains, if page access token can be used in general or if it is just a bug itself.